# How do I stop overscrolling in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, scrollview, overscroll

I have a simple list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This list view is part of an AdapterView.

In my code, I call `listView.scrollBy(deltaX,deltaY)`. This causes the list view to overscroll. The same exact code does not cause an overscroll if I use `ScrollView` instead.

Why???

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom view than extends from ListView you can override the overScrollBy function as so:

```
@Override
protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY,
  boolean isTouchEvent) 
{
    return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, 0, 0, isTouchEvent); 
}
```

Comment: Why would that (setting max overscroll) be different from using overScrollMode 'never'?